# How to set timeout of grpc client in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, grpc

I'm referring to the following example of node-grpc client:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/node/dynamic_codegen/greeter_client.js

```
//create a client
var client = new hello_proto.Greeter('localhost:50051',
                                       grpc.credentials.createInsecure());

//issue the call
  client.sayHello({name: user}, function(err, response) {
    console.log('Greeting:', response.message);
  });
```

In this call format, where do I provide the call deadline options.

Also, the jsdoc at https://grpc.io/grpc/node/ never has this kind of API calls.
Is there a good tutorial on this which covers examples like streaming rpcs, timeouts, securing the channels etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an optional argument to pass additional options between the request argument and the callback. This includes a `deadline` key. So you would do something like this:

```
client.sayHello({name: user}, {deadline: deadline}, function(err, response) {
  console.log('Greeting:', response.message);
});
```

Deadline can either be a date object or `Infinity` to explicitly not have the call time out.

This is documented, sort of, as the [`Client#makeUnaryRequest`](https://grpc.io/grpc/node/grpc.Client.html#makeUnaryRequest) function; just ignore the first three arguments. That mentions the optional `options` argument, and its type [`Client~CallOptions`](https://grpc.io/grpc/node/grpc.Client.html#~CallOptions) describes all of the options that can be passed there.

Comment: can you please give a sample example here for the deadline? Grpc server and Grpc client both